# Assertion failed md - Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, redcarpet

I noticed recently that my Jekyll site is completely blank. When I run the jekyll server locally it starts up fine, but when I change a file, it fails. The only thing out of the ordinary I recall doing is using Redcarpet.

```
~/code/ryanjm[temp*]% jekyll --server        
Configuration from /Users/ryanjm/code/ryanjm/_config.yml
Auto-regenerating enabled: /Users/ryanjm/code/ryanjm -> /Users/ryanjm/code/ryanjm/_site
[2012-10-31 22:01:27] regeneration: 49 files changed
[2012-10-31 22:01:28] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-10-31 22:01:28] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
[2012-10-31 22:01:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=41778 port=4000
[2012-10-31 22:01:32] regeneration: 1 files changed
Assertion failed: (md->work_bufs[BUFFER_BLOCK].size == 0), function sd_markdown_render, file markdown.c, line 2528.
[1]    41778 abort      jekyll --server
```

Anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

I have my project on [github](https://github.com/ryanjm/ryanjm.github.com) if you want to look at it.

I'm using rbenv with 1.9.3-p194.